# Error:Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object. Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I am trying to use a for loop to import data from a list pf file names, the code I am using is as follows:

```
for n = 2:numfiles 
     infonew{n} = char(data11{n});
end

FileID = fopen(infonew{n});
allfiles = infonew(2:numfiles)
fclose(FileID);
howmanyfiles = size(allfiles,2);

A = [];
for u = 1:howmanyfiles
   fid = fopen(allfiles{u});
end   

tline = fgets(fid);

while ischar(tline)
    parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');
    if numel(parts{1}) > 0
        A{u} = [ A{u} ; parts{:}' ];
    end
    tline = fgets(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

The `allfiles` is equal to `[1x115 char]    [1x115 char]    [1x115 char]` but can vary depending on the number and names of files chosen. Its class is a cell but I am getting the following error:

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
>
> Error in MultiSelectML>MultiSelect_Callback (line 138)   A{u} = [ A{u}
>   ; parts{:}' ];

Can anybody suggest a reason for this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: `A` is an array, not a cell array, hence `{}` are inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks, when I replace `{}` with `()` I then get the error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.  
Error in MultiSelectML>MultiSelect_Callback (line 138)
A(u) = [ A(u) ; parts{:}' ];`

Comment: Yeah, because `A` is empty and you are trying to access its uth element (which is equal to `howmanyfiles` since it's outside of the u-loop). Check your loops first, then consider loading the text as individual rows using simply `A{u}=parts` and concatenate them afterwards if you need to.

Comment: I'm really new to programming and matlab and trying to learn as I go, what way would you recommend to change the loop or with what part should I start? Thanks